# access radcombobox within a grid using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, radcombobox

I am new to jquery i have a gridview in which i am using EditItemTemplate FooterTemplate
ItemTemplate and EmptyDataTemplate for insert update of records
i am using a RadComboBox in grid whose values i want to access in client side using jquery

my markup is as follows

```
 <EditItemTemplate>
<telerik:RadComboBox TabIndex="2" ID="rcbDept" runat="server" EmptyMessage="--Select Department--" AllowCustomText="true" EnableScreenBoundaryDetection="false" Width="100px" EnableTextSelection="false" Filter="Contains" OnClientLoad="GetControlId">
 <ItemTemplate>                                                               
 <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBox1" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "dept_name") %>' />                                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnColumn" runat="server" />                                </ItemTemplate>                                                        </telerik:RadComboBox>                                                    </EditItemTemplate>
```

---

JQuery Function

```
function GetControlId()
{
 var combo = $find("<%= rcbDept.ClientID %>");
            var items = combo.get_items();
            var text = "";
            var values = "";
}
```

Any help will be highly appriciable,
thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

IF your Radcombobox is in EditItemtemplate or ItemTemplate: 
I  used this trick

Your just do this:

```
function GetControlId()
{
    var rcbDeptID=$("[id$='rcbDept']").attr("id");
    var comb0=$find(rcbDeptID);
    var items = combo.get_items();
    var text = "";
    var values = "";
}
```

**[attribute-ends-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)**